# HAProxy cannot bind socket :4443

Tags: centos7, haproxy

I'm trying to add a new port for forwarding to HAProxy but whenever I try to restart the service with the new configuration I get the error

```
haproxy-systemd-wrapper[32276]: [ALERT] 092/112955 (32277) : Starting frontend my-service: cannot bind socket [<public IP>:4443]
```

I'm running `haproxy` through `systemctl` on CentOS7. Nothing else is using port 4443 (`sudo netstat -apn | grep 4443` comes up blank), and I've got `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` and `net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1` set in sysctl.conf. I've also run `sudo setsebool -P haproxy_connect_any=1`.

The relevant part of my `haproxy.cfg` looks like this:

```
frontend my-service
   bind <public_url>:4443
   default_backend my-backend
```

I've also got other frontends binding to 80, 443 and 8080.

I've just tried adding a the port to the list of managed HTTP ports in SELinux with

```
sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 4443
```

But also with no luck

Comment: "cannot bind socket" - you should bind the port instead :)

Comment: Is that not what I'm doing in that config?